# DOM selection in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, dom

i have a table, and i did sorting of that. Its execution time bad. I guess this is because of DOM manipulation.
/* I m converting to array */

```
var rows = $table.find('tbody > tr').get(); 


 $.each(rows, function(index, row){     /*then again to 2D array */

            if(($(row).children('td').eq(0).attr('class').indexOf('collapse') != -1 || $(row).children('td').eq(0).attr('class').indexOf('expand') != -1)){ 
                myData.push(myData1);
                myData1 = [];
            }
                myData1.push(row);  
                rowCount++;
                if(rowCount == $(rows).length){ // to assign last group of rows
                myData.push(myData1);
                    myData1 = [];

            }
   });
```

which is the best way to select the DOM elements directly thorough array. Because i am using this many times.

Comment: Don't repost: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/974435/how-to-improve-performance-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's one thing you can do right away that will probably increase performance:

You see the loong chain you have to get the class values of the first `<td>` of the row? You're doing the exact same, loong, chain twice. Try

```
// then again to 2D array
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    var classes = $(row).children('td').eq(0).attr('class')
    if((classes.indexOf('collapse') != -1 || classes.indexOf('expand') != -1)){ 
        myData.push(myData1);
        myData1 = [];
    }
    myData1.push(row);
    rowCount++;
    if(rowCount == $(rows).length){ // to assign last group of rows
        myData.push(myData1);
        myData1 = [];
    }
});
```

If the `$.each()` function runs a lot of times, this should save you at least some.

Comment: thank you Tomas, is there any alternative function for $.each()

Comment: It's hard to say if there is, not knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish. See Adrian's suggestion too - is the performance good enough if you implement both of these?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the hasClass function, and using the :first selector instead of returning all tds and then only taking the first one:

`if( ($(row).children('td:first').hasClass('collapse')) ||
        ($(row).children('td:first').hasClass('expand')) {`